# Jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms

I am using this script to see if a user has left any inputs invalid clientside.

```
$('#login_submit').click(function() {

var login_email = $('#login_email').val();
var login_password = $('login_password').val();

if (login_email.length == 0) {

    $('#login_email').css('background', 'red');
}

if (login_password.length == 0) {

    $('#login_password').css('background', 'red');
}
});
```

One thing I cannot work out is how to stop the form submitting as it would. I have tried **return false;** but this then makes the input fields backgrounds just flicker red.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function() {

    var errors = 0;
    var login_email = $('#login_email').val();
    var login_password = $('login_password').val();

    if (login_email.length == 0) {
       $('#login_email').css('background', 'red');
       errors++;
     }

    if (login_password.length == 0) {
        $('#login_password').css('background', 'red');
        errors++;
     }

   return errors ? false : true;
});
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xjNut/

Just make sure you don't have an `input` with `name="submit"` in the form. All other attributes are fine to have in the input.

Comment: you understand that is just a jquery version of exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

do

```
<input type="submit" onsubmit="return submitValidate()" />
```

and change your JS to:

```
function submitValidate() {
var login_email = $('#login_email').val();
var login_password = $('login_password').val();
var submit = true;

if (login_email.length == 0) {
   submit = false;
   $('#login_email').css('background', 'red');
}

if (login_password.length == 0) {
   submit = false;
   $('#login_password').css('background', 'red');
}
return submit;
}
```

Comment: Ok will try this, can you explain why this is different? I do not understand thanks.

Comment: Instead of receiving the call for being clicked, you want to receive the call for being submitted. If you ask to receive the call for being clicked your form will say: Okay, so you are going to do this function when you are clicked, and then I will submit, whereas it now says: Okay, I have been clicked, but I want to submit, but before that I need to run this code. You understand it is all about order. If you just ask for onclick, it will still submit, but if you ask for onsubmit your form will not submit if you ask it not to.

Comment: This a bit old school. With jquery you can overwrite the click and submit functions.

Comment: I love jquery, but this is too simple for you to do, why use jquery, when you could just use old methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely because you're using a submit button:
    <input type="submit" ... />

You need to change it to a regular button:
    <input type="button" ... />

Then in your function you'll need to submit the form when the code is valid:
    $('#formId').submit();